# I'm getting an error of 13:5 error The "Home" component has been registered but not used vue/no-unused-components

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm getting this error in Vue. I've never worked with Vue before and was trying to build out a website using Vue/CLI. I was just planning to reorganize and build inward-out, but like I said I've never used Vue and I don't know how to remedy this error. All I did was slightly modify some of the names on the code and delete items I wasn't using.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <CompanyName msg="AutoSentinel"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Home from './components/Homepage.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Home
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="Home">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>
      Welcome to AutoSentinel
    </p><br>
    <p>
      Where driving meets safety
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#drowsiness" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Drowsiness</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sos" target="_blank" rel="noopener">SOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#map" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="#drivers" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Drivers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#data" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Data</a></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

It tells me home has been registered but not used. How do I fix this?

Comment: Replace `<CompanyName msg="AutoSentinel"/>` with `<home msg="AutoSentinel"/>`

Comment: I realized that shortly after my post. I was just being a silly goose, I guess.

Comment: So did you issue resolved?

Comment: I did. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In App vue

tag inside template->div tag and refresh localhost page

Comment: <template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
    <home msg="AutoSentinel"/>
  </div>
</template>

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Can you add more information?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove import of Home

```
import Home from './components/Homepage.vue'
```

And, delete Home from Components

```
components: {
    Home
}
```

You have imported **Home** component, you have registered it in **app**. But, You are not using it in the **view** part of the **app** component.